# Forcing Excel to stop calculating after error in function

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a function defined that is called over 1000 times on the spreadsheet (looks up a price from the database)  Occasionally the spreadsheet is opened in an environment where the database is unavailable.  When that happens, I've got error code to handle it, which pushes a message box.

I'd like a way to stop the Excel calculation if the first one fails, so things can be fixed. I'd pop a message box that gives the option to stop calculation.

Is there a way to make this happen?  As of now, it basically pops the message box 1000 times, and a lot of time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> (some keyboards do not even have a break key) or <kbd>Esc</kbd> will not stop the running because it goes too quick to get the break in...

```
ErrorHandler:
' clean up
If Not rst1 Is Nothing Then
    If rst1.State = adStateOpen Then rst1.Close
End If
Set rst1 = Nothing

If Not Con1 Is Nothing Then
    If Con1.State = adStateOpen Then Con1.Close
End If
Set Con1 = Nothing

If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
End If


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a label and divert to label using goto. See below code.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


a = 1 / 0

ErrorHandler:
' clean up
If Not rst1 Is Nothing Then
    If rst1.State = adStateOpen Then rst1.Close
End If
Set rst1 = Nothing

If Not Con1 Is Nothing Then
    If Con1.State = adStateOpen Then Con1.Close
End If
Set Con1 = Nothing

If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
    GoTo exit_func
End If

exit_func:

End Function
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to stop the calculations in Excel...and really doesn't do anything more than the listed code.  Exiting the function doesn't stop the macros, or stop calculations.

Comment: @OneTallShort Does it still pops the message box 1000 times?

Comment: Sure, because the function is called 1000 times from the spreadsheet...not looped 1000 times..This is defined as a function, not a macro sub routine.  It's called like =GetPrice(A1, C1, D1) so when excel is calculating, it's trying to update every instance of the function on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by setting your function as boolean, i try to explain to you by using the example below:

```
Sub plus()

Dim cond As Boolean
Dim a As Integer

cond = True  'initialize the condition

Dim rowA As Long
rowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 1 To 3   'calling to loop to call function 
    If cond = True Then
        cond = plusnumber(cond, rowA) ' passing the data to function
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The following is the function which is the boolean type that I mentioned just now:

```
Function plusnumber(condition, rowA) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To rowA
    If Range("A" & i).Value > 5 Then
        MsgBox "the number greater than 5)"
        plusnumber = False 'set the condition as false and exit function
        Exit Function
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value + Range("A" & i).Value
    End If
Next


End Function
```

Hope it help you.